# Token-2022 in Anchor-Spl 0.28.0 version

Tags: anchor, token-2022

Thanks for your concerns.

I was building smart contract on Solana. I used token-2022 and anchor_spl::token_interface::{Mint, TokenAccount}

I checked Mint and TokenAccount. There is Owners trait instead of Owner trait

But #[derive(Accounts)] macro needs Owner trait I guess

How can I fix this glitch?[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`token_interface` requires using `InterfaceAccount` instead of `Account`.

This won't work:

```
pub token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
```

Correct usage is:

```
pub token_account: InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!!